# How to return non-entity json from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Im making a rest api and have several controllers using respond_to and respond_with and it all works fine.

```
class ItemController < ApiController
    respond_to :json
    def index
       respond_with Item.all
    end
end
```

I want to have a controller returning JSON not based on an entity

```
class ReportController < ApiController

    def index
         @mylist << {
              :id => 1,
              :name => "test"
         }
         what goes here to return @mylist as json ?
    end
end
```

I've attempted a few different variations of returning @mylist , which give me errors like

undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the error `undefined method << for nil:NilClass.`, you need to initialize the variable.

```
class ReportController < ApiController

    def index
         @mylist = []
         @mylist << {
              :id => 1,
              :name => "test"
         }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
render json: @mylist
```

or:

```
respond_with @mylist
```

And fix your variable this way:

```
 @mylist = [ { id: 1, name: "test" } ]
```